# This Web Page Has a Re-Direct Loop

Tags: php

Not sure what's going on with my page but whenever I try to load it, it displays `This Web Page Has a Re-Direct Loop.`

Personally, I think it has something to do with the first line with the include.

**Code**:

```
<?PHP
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/admin/classes/classes.php');        // Include local class lib

$log= new log($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

?>

*/
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/facebook.php');

class FBData{
    /**
    *   SET THE FOLLOWING CONST VARIABLES
    */
    const app_id='';
    const app_secret='';
    const admintoken='';
    const adminuser='';

    /**
    *   user_ports take user ids and port them to user ids locally
    */
    //public static  $user_ports=array('45403199'=>'3'); 
    public static $user_ports=array();
    public static  $dont_alert=array('1');

    public function updatecount($uid){

        $senduser = new Profile($uid);
        $uinfo=$senduser->profile;

        $tfbid=self::get_fbid($uid);


        if($uinfo['activeaccount']>1&&!in_array($tfbid,self::$dont_alert)){
            $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => self::app_id,'secret' => self::app_secret,));
        }

    }

    public function get_fbid($uid){

        $revports=self::$user_ports;
        $revports=array_flip($revports);

            if($revports[$uid]>0)
                    $tfbid=$revports[$uid];
                else
                    $tfbid=$uid;

        return($tfbid);
    }

    public function clearcount($uid){

        $senduser = new Profile($uid);
        $uinfo=$senduser->profile;

        $tfbid=self::get_fbid($uid);


        if($uinfo['activeaccount']>1&&!in_array($tfbid,self::$dont_alert)){
            $atoken=self::admintoken;
            $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => self::app_id,'secret' => self::app_secret,));
              try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $update=$facebook ->api(array('method' => 'dashboard.setCount', 'uid' => $tfbid, 'access_token' => $atoken, 'count'=>'0', 'format'=>'json'));
              } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                //echo "failed"; die();
              }

            $apprequests = $facebook->api('/me/apprequests');       
            $appreq=$apprequests['data'];
            foreach($appreq as $appreqdat){
                $apprequestsresult = $facebook->api($appreqdat['id'], 'DELETE');
            }
        }

    }


}



    $app_id=FBData::app_id;
    $app_secret=FBData::app_secret;
    $admintoken=FBData::admintoken;
    $fulladmintoken='access_token='.$admintoken;
    $user_ports=FBData::$user_ports;
    $reverse_ports=array_flip($user_ports);
    $fbreq_friend="I added you as a friend on HarvardConnection! Join me there, its the original facebook!";
    $fbreq_message="I sent a message to you, but to view it you have to sign up at HarvardConnection. Its the original facebook!";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $app_id,
      'secret' => $app_secret,
    ));


/*

Start the site

*/  

$site=new Site();
if($site->get_setting('site_on')==0){
    header("Location: thewebsiteisdownahhhh.php"); 
    die(); 
}



// TRIGGERS

/*
Last Activity 
DROP TRIGGER log_trigger;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER log_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON log
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
REPLACE INTO `last_activity` (`last`, `user_id`) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NEW.userid);
IF (Select count(1) from `Hits_Per_Day` WHERE `date`=CURDATE())=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO `Hits_Per_Day` (`date`,`hits`) VALUES (CURDATE(),'1');
ELSE
    UPDATE `Hits_Per_Day` SET `hits`=`hits`+1 WHERE `date`=CURDATE();
END IF;
IF (Select count(1) from `Hits_Per_Month` WHERE `date`=concat(YEAR(curdate()),"-",month(curdate()),"-0"))=0 THEN
    INSERT INTO `Hits_Per_Month` (`date`,`hits`) VALUES (concat(YEAR(curdate()),"-",month(curdate()),"-0"),'1');
ELSE
    UPDATE `Hits_Per_Month` SET `hits`=`hits`+1 WHERE `date`=concat(YEAR(curdate()),"-",month(curdate()),"-0");
END IF;
IF NEW.userid>0 AND (Select count(1) from `log` WHERE `userid`=NEW.userid AND `timestamp`>CURDATE())=1 THEN
    IF (Select count(1) from `Users_Per_Day` WHERE `date`=CURDATE())=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `Users_Per_Day` (`date`,`hits`) VALUES (CURDATE(),'1');
    ELSE
        UPDATE `Users_Per_Day` SET `hits`=`hits`+1 WHERE `date`=CURDATE();
    END IF;
END IF;
IF (Select count(1) from `log` WHERE `ip`=NEW.ip AND `timestamp`>CURDATE())=1 THEN
    IF (Select count(1) from `Uniques_Per_Day` WHERE `date`=CURDATE())=0 THEN
        INSERT INTO `Uniques_Per_Day` (`date`,`hits`) VALUES (CURDATE(),'1');
    ELSE
        UPDATE `Uniques_Per_Day` SET `hits`=`hits`+1 WHERE `date`=CURDATE();
    END IF;
END IF;
END;

|

DELIMITER ;

// sync tables
REPLACE INTO last_activity
SELECT last,`userid` as `user_id` 
FROM lastactivity
*/

/*
Last Update

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER lu_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON profileupdates
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
REPLACE INTO `last_update` (`last`, `user_id`) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), NEW.userid);
END;

|

DELIMITER ;

// sync tables
REPLACE INTO last_update
SELECT last,`userid` as `user_id` 
FROM lastupdate









*/
?>
```

Comment: please show your code

Comment: classes.php might be useful

Comment: have you debugged it? Have you tried something with yourself?

Comment: updated with classes.php code

Comment: Seems like this line to me: `if($site->get_setting('site_on')==0){ header("Location: thewebsiteisdownahhhh.php"); `

Comment: ah, yes. I see, how can I fix this?